# Can the ShortTitles key be used with InAppSettingsKit PSMultiValueSpecifiers?

Tags: objective-c, ios, plist, inappsettingskit

i'm using InAppSettingsKit and i'm trying to include the key "ShortTitles" in my plist file per: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/PSMultiValueSpecifier.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007016-SW1

```
        <dict>
        <key>DefaultValue</key>
        <string>0</string>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>preferenceName</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>MyPreferenceTitle</string>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSMultiValueSpecifier</string>
        <key>ShortTitles</key>
        <array>
            <string>None</string>
            <string>Type1</string>
            <string>Type2</string>
        </array>
        <key>Titles</key>
        <array>
            <string>None</string>
            <string>Type1: description</string>
            <string>Type2: description</string>
        </array>
        <key>Values</key>
        <array>
            <string>0</string>
            <string>1</string>
            <string>2</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

but it doesn't seem to be taking effect and only the Titles key is being used. am i missing something or is this key not allowed by IASK?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what IASK is, but the ShortTitles only work in iOS 5.0.

Comment: thanks for reply. i am targeting iOS 5.0... still not working


http://www.inappsettingskit.com/